# Get data associated to ggplot + stat_ecdf()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I like the **stat_ecdf()** feature part of ggplot2 package, which I find quite useful to explore a data series. However this is only visual, and I wonder if it is feasible - and if yes how - to get the associated table?

Please have a look to the following reproducible example

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length")) + stat_ecdf() # building of the cumulated chart 
p
attributes(p) # chart attributes
p$data # data is iris dataset, not the serie used for displaying the chart
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `ecdf` function included in base R if you just want to estimate the empirical cdf without plotting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can recreate the data:

```
#Recreate ecdf data
dat_ecdf <- 
  data.frame(x=unique(iris$Sepal.Length),
             y=ecdf(iris$Sepal.Length)(unique(iris$Sepal.Length))*length(iris$Sepal.Length))
#rescale y to 0,1 range
dat_ecdf$y <- 
  scale(dat_ecdf$y,center=min(dat_ecdf$y),scale=diff(range(dat_ecdf$y)))
```

Below 2 plots should look the same:

```
#plot using new data
ggplot(dat_ecdf,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_step() +
  xlim(4,8)

#plot with built-in stat_ecdf
ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length")) +
  stat_ecdf() +
  xlim(4,8)
```

Answer (score 5):

As @krfurlong showed me in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062217/create-a-table-with-values-from-ecdf-graph), the `layer_data` function in ggplot2 can get you exactly what you're looking for without the need to recreate the data.

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length")) + stat_ecdf()
p.data <- layer_data(p)
```

The first column in p.data, "y", contains the ecdf values. "x" is the Sepal.Length values on the x-axis in your plot.