# which.max not functioning as expected

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table that includes the value of y for when x is equal to or less than a certain value, by group. Below is my code using the iris data set.

For "<=2.5", I expect to get 4.5, 5.0, or 5.8 for the virginica group, since these are the values of Petal.Length associated with a Sepal.Width of 2.5 for virginica. But instead, I get 6.0. Any ideas of where I went wrong? (My actual data set does not have duplicates of the variable analogous to Sepal.Width for the same group, so choosing among those is not an issue for me.)

```
data(iris)

my.table <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise("<=2.5" = Petal.Length[which.max(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width<=2.5])],
            "<=3" = Petal.Length[which.max(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width<=3])],
            "<=3.5" = Petal.Length[which.max(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width<=3.5])],
            "<=4" = Petal.Length[which.max(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width<=4])])
```

This is related to the question [Create a table with values from ecdf graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062217/create-a-table-with-values-from-ecdf-graph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are *first* subsetting the `Sepal.Width`. Consequently, the index returned by `which.max` applies to that sub-vector, and no longer corresponds to the indices of the whole `Petal.Length` vector.

To fix this, you also need to subset `Petal.Length` correspondingly, e.g.

```
…
`<=2.5` = Petal.Length[Sepal.Width <= 2.5][which.max(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width <= 2.5])],
…
```

… of course this gets rather verbose and repetitive. It might be better to perform the subsetting in a separate step. However, this means creating new columns for every threshold value.

Incidentally, this is unrelated to dplyr.

Answer (score 3):

To make it more scalable, using double loop:

```
myCuts <- c(2.5, 3, 3.5, 4)

res <- sapply(split(iris, iris$Species), function(i)
  sapply(myCuts, function(j){
    x <- i[ i$Sepal.Width <= j, ]
    x$Petal.Length[ which.max(x$Sepal.Width) ]
  }))

rownames(res) <- paste0("<=", myCuts)
res
#       setosa versicolor virginica
# <=2.5    1.3        3.9       4.5
# <=3      1.4        4.2       5.9
# <=3.5    1.4        4.5       5.6
# <=4      1.2        4.5       6.7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to get the same data. Create a group variable according to Sepal.Width values. Then within each group, select the row with the top Sepal.Width value. It is in a different "shape", but you can always `pivot_wider` if you want all the values as columns instead of rows.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species,
           Sepal.Width_grp = case_when(Sepal.Width <= 2.5 ~ '<=2.5',
                                       Sepal.Width <= 3 ~ '<=3',
                                       Sepal.Width <= 3.5 ~ '<=3.5',
                                       Sepal.Width <= 4 ~ '<=4',
                                       TRUE ~ '> 4')) %>%
  top_n(1, -Sepal.Width) %>% 
  select(Species, Sepal.Width_grp, Top.Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width, Petal.Width)
# # A tibble: 25 x 4
# # Groups:   Species, Sepal.Width_grp [12]
#    Species Sepal.Width_grp Top.Sepal.Width Petal.Width
#    <fct>   <chr>                     <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1 setosa  <=3.5                       3.1         0.2
#  2 setosa  <=4                         3.6         0.2
#  3 setosa  <=3                         2.9         0.2
#  4 setosa  <=3.5                       3.1         0.1
#  5 setosa  <=4                         3.6         0.2
#  6 setosa  <=3.5                       3.1         0.2
#  7 setosa  > 4                         4.1         0.1
#  8 setosa  <=3.5                       3.1         0.2
#  9 setosa  <=4                         3.6         0.1
# 10 setosa  <=2.5                       2.3         0.3
# # ... with 15 more rows
```

Edit: A little simpler if you use `cut`

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species,
           Sepal.Width_grp = cut(Sepal.Width, c(0, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, Inf))) %>% 
  top_n(1, -Sepal.Width) %>% 
  select(Species, Sepal.Width_grp, Top.Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width, Petal.Width)
# # A tibble: 25 x 4
# # Groups:   Species, Sepal.Width_grp [12]
#    Species Sepal.Width_grp Top.Sepal.Width Petal.Width
#    <fct>   <fct>                     <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1 setosa  (3,3.5]                     3.1         0.2
#  2 setosa  (3.5,4]                     3.6         0.2
#  3 setosa  (2.5,3]                     2.9         0.2
#  4 setosa  (3,3.5]                     3.1         0.1
#  5 setosa  (3.5,4]                     3.6         0.2
#  6 setosa  (3,3.5]                     3.1         0.2
#  7 setosa  (4,Inf]                     4.1         0.1
#  8 setosa  (3,3.5]                     3.1         0.2
#  9 setosa  (3.5,4]                     3.6         0.1
# 10 setosa  (0,2.5]                     2.3         0.3
# # ... with 15 more rows
```